# How to use Custom Component in Workflow?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I want to create a custom component to create some folders in the desired series. I've the java code the does this job and is running fine. But I'm not able to use the component after deploying. The problem I face is that the methods are not available for me to choose in the workflow.

If I deploy a simple component without any supporting jar file, it is working properly.

1. How to add component with supporting jars?
2. How to remove old components without re initializing the entire isolated region?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Define component  Queue in the process config console and add jar or JMS  code.
In the workflow define component step and invoke tht operation in the workflow. IN PTM give the necessary jar files and start the PTm and component integrator.